# Optimizing canvas multiple objects rendering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rendering, pixi.js

I'm trying to make an ants simulator, I use the basic Javascript canvas renderer

here is a part of the rendering code :

```
render(simulation) {
    
    let ctx = this.ctx;
    
    // Clear previous frame
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    
    // Pheromones
    let pheromone;
    let pheromoneXPos;
    let pheromoneYPos;
    for (let i = 0; i < simulation.pheromones.length; i++) {
      pheromone = simulation.pheromones[i];
      pheromoneXPos = pheromone.position[0];
      pheromoneYPos = pheromone.position[1];
      ctx.fillRect(pheromoneXPos, pheromoneYPos, 1, 1);
    }
    
    
    // ... rendering other stuff
    
}
```

here is an example (it runs smoothly just because I'm using ~90% fewer objects) :

[image]

The `simulation.pheromones.length` is quite large (~25000), the time it takes to render 1 frame is too long (250ms on my computer)
What should I do to make it render faster? should I use a rendering engine (like PixiJS) instead? or am I just using it wrong?

Note: most of the objects (Pheromones) are the same as the previous frame (they only update once or twice every second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems all your rectangles have the same style, you could combine all these rectangles in a single sub-path and call `fill()` only once with this more complex sub-path.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const w = canvas.width = 500;
const h = canvas.height = 500;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const makePheromone = () => ({
  x: w / 2,
  y: h / 2,
  dx: Math.random() * 20 - 10,
  dy: Math.random() * 20 - 10
});
const pheromones = Array.from( { length: 50000 }, makePheromone );
ctx.fillStyle = "red";

requestAnimationFrame( draw );

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  ctx.beginPath();
  pheromones.forEach( (obj) => {
    obj.x += obj.dx;
    if( obj.x < 0 ) {
      obj.x += w; 
    }
    else if( obj.x > w ) {
      obj.x -= w; 
    }
    obj.y += obj.dy;
    if( obj.y < 0 ) {
      obj.y += h; 
    }
    else if( obj.y > h ) {
      obj.y -= h; 
    }
    ctx.rect( obj.x, obj.y, 1, 1 );
  });
  ctx.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame( draw );
}
```

```html
<canvas width="5000" height="5000"></canvas>
```

Now, it's quite unclear if in your case you will actually animate these 'pheromones' or not.
If you don't, then draw them only once and store an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) from the canvas that you will render every frame:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const w = canvas.width = 500;
const h = canvas.height = 500;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

getPheromonesBitmap()
  .then( (bmp) => {
    let x = w / 2;
    let y = h / 2;
    const circle = new Path2D();
    circle.arc( 0, 0, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2 ); 
    function draw( t ) {
      x += Math.sin( t / 2000 );
      y += Math.cos( t / 2000 );  
      ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 );
      ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, w, h );
      // draw all the pheromones as a single bitmap
      ctx.drawImage( bmp, 0, 0 );
      ctx.translate( x, y );
      ctx.fill( circle );
      requestAnimationFrame( draw );
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( draw );
  } );

function getPheromonesBitmap() {
  const makePheromone = () => ({
    x: Math.random() * w,
    y: Math.random() * h
  });
  const pheromones = Array.from( { length: 50000 }, makePheromone );
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  ctx.beginPath();
  pheromones.forEach( (obj) => {
    ctx.rect( obj.x, obj.y, 1, 1 );
  });
  ctx.fill();
  const prom = createImageBitmap( canvas );
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, w, h );
  return prom;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="5000" height="5000"></canvas>
```

For browsers that don't support `createImageBitmap` (only Safari for this simple case), I wrote a polyfill available [here](https://github.com/Kaiido/createImageBitmap).

And finally, in case you do draw your 1x1px rectangles at pixel boundaries, you could also use an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) to render these, which is particularly performant for when all entities have their own color:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const w = canvas.width = 500;
const h = canvas.height = 500;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const makePheromone = () => ({
  x: w / 2,
  y: h / 2,
  dx: Math.random() * 20 - 10,
  dy: Math.random() * 20 - 10,
  color: Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF
});
const pheromones = Array.from( { length: 50000 }, makePheromone );
const img = new ImageData( w, h );
// we use an Uint32Array to set each pixel in one pass
const arr = new Uint32Array( img.data.buffer );

requestAnimationFrame( draw );

function draw() {
  pheromones.forEach( (obj) => {
    obj.x += obj.dx;
    if( obj.x < 0 ) {
      obj.x += w; 
    }
    else if( obj.x > w ) {
      obj.x -= w; 
    }
    obj.y += obj.dy;
    if( obj.y < 0 ) {
      obj.y += h; 
    }
    else if( obj.y > h ) {
      obj.y -= h; 
    }
    const index = Math.floor( obj.y * w + obj.x );
    arr[ index ] = obj.color + 0xFF000000;
  });
  ctx.putImageData( img, 0, 0 );
  requestAnimationFrame( draw );
}
```

```html
<canvas width="5000" height="5000"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, thank you for the detailed answer, I tried what you suggested with some modifications and stored all the `pheromones` on `Uint8ClampedArray` and then set the buffer to `ImageData`, and it performed great. Now I just need to make them lose strength (alpha) over time, it there a way to apply an opacity filter to a `Uint8ClampedArray` without going through every pixel?

Comment: Not really, but I'm quite surprised it's the solution you choose. Could you clarify a bit your exact case: are these animated, with various colors, do each pheromone has its own alpha or is it global?

Comment: The pheromones are just static dots (two types: green and blue) that decay over time, each time an ant makes a step forward it leaves a pheromone behind, and when it wants to find the way home it follows the smell of those pheromones. So I can treat them like an image and reduce their opacity over time.